# iOS webauthn error: This request has been canceled by the user

Tags: ios, webauthn

When the user closes the webauthn pop-up window, it is not possible to recall the pop-up window again, but instead an error is prompted.

When the user closes the webauthn pop-up window, it is not possible to recall the pop-up window again, but instead error: This request has been canceled by the user

Answer (score 0):

When the user closes the webauthn pop-up window, it is not possible to recall the pop-up window again, but instead an error is prompted.

The actual error issue is:

[Warning] User gesture is not detected. To use the WebAuthn API, call 'navigator.credentials.create' or 'navigator.credentials.get' within user activated events.

This issue is caused by multiple asynchronous processing operations before using 'navigator.credentials.create' or 'navigator.credentials.get'.

Before using 'navigator.credentials.create' or 'navigator.credentials.get', only up to one asynchronous process (including requests) is allowed.

Troubleshooting this issue took over a day, so I hope this helps others.

Reference link: https://fy.blackhats.net.au/blog/2020-08-12-user-gesture-is-not-detected-using-ios-touchid-with-webauthn-rs/

Comment: PS: iOS Chrome has the same problem. What we need to do is troubleshoot the function calls at each step and reduce the asynchronous await processing to just one.